# Обмен данными между двумя клиентами (браузерами)

Tags: веб-программирование, передача-данных

Приветствую. Как осуществить обмен данными: клиент <-> клиент? Возможно ли такое с помощю ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Да, это возможно!** Но есть детали.

*Это не AJAX, конечно (я позволил себе сократить требования до "браузера без плагинов"). Но рядом с ответами про вебсокеты и громкие заявления о том, что это невозможно, считаю нужным возразить.*

### Если коротко, WebRTC.

---

**Даже для этого потребуется участие сервера (но только в начале!)**, поскольку клиенты должны узнавать о существовании друг друга.

Через **"сигнальный сервер"** они объединяются в комнаты и с помощью ICE (Interactive Connectivity Establishment) пытаются подсоединиться друг к другу напрямую, обходя NATы. Потребуется STUN-сервер (чтобы клиент узнавал собственный адрес/порт и мог его объявить), а для безнадёжных случаев, где прямая связь не устанавливается, TURN-шлюз для прокачки пакетов. Последний необязателен, но позволит соединяться в большем числе сценариев.

Означенный сигнальный сервер всего лишь управляет раздачей ICE-предложений (пакетов с информацией о клиентах) в пределах комнаты: клиент заявляет о себе, а сервер рассылает заявление тем, кому нужно о нём знать. Логику, конечно, можно изменить. Популярный способ реализации: NodeJS+socket.io (Websockets + запасные варианты).

#### Но это:

- Поддерживают только достаточно свежие браузеры.
- Не всегда работает и в печальных случаях требует TURN-сервер для прокачки пакетов, когда клиенты неудачно расположены в сети.
- Довольно... непривычный интерфейс после клиент-серверной связи.

Comment: А эсли один клиент знает ип адрес другого то нужен ли в начале сервер?

Comment: @Ezdrael есть публичные сигнальные сервера. Но чтоб совсем -- этого не знаю. В теории, если воспроизвести ICE Candidate от другого хоста, можно попытаться вклиниться в ICE с середины... Но я не видел чтобы кто-либо так делал.

Comment: @Ezdrael ...надо смотреть на содержимое кандидата и характер данных там. Вероятно, его можно передать и без сервера, скажем, по телефону :)

Comment: Способ хорош. В скором будущем когда все браузеры подтянутся будет самое то. Но позволю себе заметить что автор пилит игру, и в этом контексте сложновато будет обойтись без сервера, а раз у нас есть сервер.... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Upd:** Это ответ на первую версию вопроса *Ajax обмен Обмен данными между двумя клиентами*.

Это невозможно. Ajax предназначен для обмена данными между клиентом и сервером. Также обратите внимание на то, что обмен данными по прежнему остается односторонним и направлен от браузера (клиент) к веб-серверу (сервер). То есть клиент отправляет запрос, а сервер обрабатывает его и отправляет ответ.

> [AJAX, Ajax](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)
>   (ˈeɪdʒæks, от англ. Asynchronous Javascript and XML — «асинхронный JavaScript и XML») — подход к построению интерактивных пользовательских интерфейсов веб-приложений, заключающийся в «фоновом» обмене данными браузера с веб-сервером. В результате, при обновлении данных веб-страница не перезагружается полностью, и веб-приложения становятся быстрее и удобнее.

Двусторонний обмен данными браузер <-> браузер (клиент <-> клиент) можно реализовать используя на клиентской стороне [Websockets](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) и сервер который поддерживает Websockets. Серверная реализация Websockets доступна для множества популярных языков программирования.

Примерный алгоритм работы:

- Клиенты соединяются посредством веб-сокетов с сервером.
- Сервер содержит список подключенных клиентов.
- Клиент посылает данные серверу, в результате чего сервер отправляет всем или части клиентам эти же данные (проксирование) или любые другие данные.

**Важно понимать,** что для грамотного решения поставленной задачи следует использовать постоянное двунаправленное соединение между двумя узлами. В Вашем случае (определено на основании тега `ajax`) клиентами выступают браузеры, для которых не существует способа напрямую соединиться. Поэтому немного усложнив схему взаимодействия путем ввода промежуточного звена в виде сервера получаем желаемый результат.

Comment: А как возможно? Эсть чтото что могло бы это сделать?

Comment: @Ezdrael, обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую клиента с клиентом соединить не получится. В любом случае между ними должен быть сервер. Предлагаю посмотреть в сторону Websockets. [Пример](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets):

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://javascript.ru/ws");

socket.onopen = function() {
  alert("Соединение установлено.");
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
  } else {
    alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
  }
  alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
};
```

Comment: и что в рамках изначального вопроса изменится "посмотрев на вебсокеты" по сравнению с ajax?

Comment: Спасибо. Я посмотрю